# Error: Not found: 'dart:ui' import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;

Tags: android, flutter

Blockquote

> Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
> import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;

Comment: Does your `pubspec.yaml` file have the [Flutter SDK listed as a dependency](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/pubspec)?

Answer (score 0):

Use F5 to run your code instead of the "Run code" button (the triangle icon on the top right), because vscode will run the file you are currently using not the whole project.