# import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;

Tags: flutter, dart

flutter error

> enter cimport 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble; how to import dart ui in vs code this is the default code
> ode here

Comment: Why is this tagged visual studio 2010 and java? Please post your code and ask a full question.

Comment: [Don't repost the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71986073/).  You also didn't answer my comment on that one.